# clipped values on x-axis

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

pyqtgraph plot clips most right x-axis value

[image]

Same happens with y-axis values if I add a y-axis label.

I added margins:

```
self.plotView.plot.setContentsMargins(10, 0, 10, 0)
```

But got another problem. Now when I resize plot it preserves part of last value in margin space:

[image]

I'm using PyQt5 on Debian Stretch.

May be someone already faced with that problem.
Any suggestions are welcome.

### UPDATE:

After some experiments and tests with standard pyqtgraph examples that I took from [that github account](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph) I found the same odd behavior with big numbers on x-axis:

**Plotting.py example:**

[preserved part of last value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ni5N.png)

[cliped most right x-axis value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvFUA.png)

Also tried PlotWidget.py example, same problem.

The only thing that I want to know, is that OS(Desktop Environment?) dependent problem or no?

Currently I'm using Debian Stretch under GNOME3 Environment.

Thanks for any contribution!

Comment: @eyllanesc , thanks for edits

Comment: In this kind of problems we need a [mcve]